# What exactly are dried anchovies?

Tags: fish, drying

As the question states.  Have these been cooked in any way or just dry cured with salt etc?

If I want to make my own dried anchovies, how do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Dried anchovies are common as snacks in Japan and Korea. As a snacks, there must be preprocessing (heating and drying in big machines) to make them soft and dry, so we can eat the bone.:P

And dried anchovies as snacks are also quite easy to find as snacks and with many flavours:
http://www.maangchi.com/ingredient/dried-anchovies-myulchi

There are also kind of Salted fish common in South China, or Hong Kong, which is sun-dried for weeks or month after salting them. Large fish would be used and would cook before serving/ eating, and is usually used to boost the taste of another dish, and seldom just eat it alone cause it is too salty. While these Salted fish could be self made, and cook it after salted. 
Different from dried anchovies, which should be cooked and dried as a snacks
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Japan, the fresh anchovies are first boiled/simmered in sea water(or 3% salt water).

Then, it is dried naturally under strong sunlight or via drying machines.

Apparently very fresh anchovies should be used or the end product won't taste very good.